# How to get text in dash using dialog box?

Tags: dialog, plotly-dash

I want to ask name of plot by using dialog box in dash like promp function in javascript but when I use `{html.Script("prompt('text');", type='text/javascript')` I have nothing in return.

I don't want to use text input or text area.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Dash documentation says the following on `html.Script`:

> CAUTION:  is included for completeness, but you cannot execute JavaScript code by providing it to a  element. Use a clientside callback for this purpose instead.

https://dash.plotly.com/dash-html-components/script

As the documentation says here one option would be to use a clientside callback instead.

Minimal example to show the idea:

```
app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(id="content"),
        html.Button(id="button", children="Show name of plot prompt"),
    ]
)


app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(n_clicks) {
      if (n_clicks) {
        nameOfPlot = prompt('name of plot')
        return nameOfPlot
      }
      return "Name of plot placeholder"
    }
    """,
    Output("content", "children"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
)
```

The `Button` click is the input for this callback. If nothing is clicked I return a placeholder text which sets the `children` property of a div with id `content`.

If the button has been clicked we can call `prompt` and do something with it.

With this approach you need an input and an output for the callback to work. You could also put the Javascript code in a `.js` file in an `assets` in your root application directory. For more info on client side callbacks see the documentation [here](https://dash.plotly.com/clientside-callbacks).

Another approach would be to have a `.js` file in your `assets` folder and to put your prompt code there. You'd probably also want to set up some event listeners to wait for the page to load and/or to listen for button click events or other events that you could use to trigger the prompt at the right moment.